# How to describe a testcase inside an it() in jasmine

Tags: jasmine

This is my code so far:

```
import diceroll, {maxVal, minVal} from './index';

let testset=[
  // definition, min, max
  ["1",1,1],
  ["w6",1,6],
  ["1w6",1,6],
  ["2w6",2,12],
  ["2w6+12",14,24],
  ["2w6+12+2w3",16,30],
  ["3w6-3",0,15],
];

describe('lib/diceroll', () => {
  it('should parse correctly', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < testset.length; i++) {
      let definition = testset[i][0];
      let minToBe = testset[i][1];
      let maxToBe = testset[i][2];

      let min = minVal(definition);
      let max = maxVal(definition);

      // @todo: OnFailure tell me the current definition!

      expect(minVal(definition)).toBe(minToBe);
      expect(maxVal(definition)).toBe(maxToBe);

      for (let n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        let r = diceroll(definition);
        expect(r).toBeLessThanOrEqual(minToBe);
        expect(r).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(maxToBe);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

My problem: If some expectation failes I do not know which diceroll-definition was failing. I tried to call a describe() inside an it() - which is not allowed.

What is the best practice here? Using it() inside my testset-loop? Or am I doing something completely off here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine matchers have an optional second argument:

> `(method) jasmine.Matchers<number>.toBeLessThanOrEqual(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean`

So you could write something like the following to output where the failure occurred:

```
for (let n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
  let r = diceroll(definition);
  expect(r).toBeLessThanOrEqual(minToBe, 'failed when i='+i+' n='+n);
  expect(r).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(maxToBe, 'failed when i='+i+' n='+n);
}
```

Comment: That is helpful. Thank you so far. I still dislike having the complete test inside one it() ...

Comment: You can nest describes within describes.  If you structure it that way, just place the `it()` at the end for the expectations.

Comment: So I can run code (like a for loop) inside a describe() but outside a it()? I was unsure about side effects and sticking to best practise.